# Изменение стиля при нажатии на текст или div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Имеем:

```
// php код
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}\" id=\"si_aa".$m4["id"]."\">
    <input type=\"checkbox\">
</a>
```

По сути ссылка, которая данные отправляет через ajax (оч не охота трогать id, т.к. он с данными) Внутри ссылки чекбокс. Нажимаем и снимаем чекбоксы - данные отправляются, все весело.

Можно ли Чекбокс заменить на текст, что бы при нажатии/отжатии div у текста меняли свойства style? (охота не задеть ajax)

```
// не нажали
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}\" id=\"si_aaconf\">
    <div style=\"тут_я_чего_ни_будь_напишу_1\">слово</div>
</a>
// нажали, стиль другой
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}\" id=\"si_aaconf\">
    <div style=\"тут_я_чего_ни_будь_напишу_2\">слово</div>
</a>
```

т.е. что то вроде подобия чекбокса получается - видно что нажато, а что нет

Comment: Почему у вас в стилях присутствуют кавычки {,}? Плюс, откуда должны браться стили для div'a?

Comment: это для ajax, он так правильнее работает (кроме того именно так мне написали гуру хэшкода - работает, не смею спорить). div - ну просто напишу:

    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#4488CC;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить элемент, который находится в элементе, то это просто:

js

```
function getElem(elem) {
   var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');
   var first_el = elems[0];

   if(first_el.getAttribute('active') == undefined || first_el.getAttribute('active') == '0') {
      first_el.style.color = 'red';
      first_el.setAttribute('active', '1');
   }
   else {
      first_el.style.color = 'blue';
      first_el.setAttribute('active', '0');
   }

}
```

html

```
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}\" id=\"si_aaconf\" onclick="getElem(this);">
    <div style=\"тут_я_чего_ни_будь_напишу_2\">слово</div>
</a>
```

Comment: работает! к сожалению только в одну сторону работает. т.к. нажать можно, если нажать второй раз обратно стиль не меняется, и к сожалению стиль прописан оч. строго (виноват. пример привел только с background-color)

Comment: А мы вот возьмем, да добавим атрибут тегу. С помощью js будет проверять, какое значение установлено у этого атрибута и подставлять нужный нам стиль. Обновил пост.

Comment: гениально! сейчас сам попробую исправить style на class, т.к. спросил неправильно, хотя не спец в js. буду рад если кто поможет

Comment: **дабы не плодить темы**, прошу помочь, изменить style на class, т.к. в JS не разобрался c classes, что бы классы переключать

Comment: elem.className = 'traTaTa';