# Отметка ссылок с ограничителем

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

[Вчера, вооружившись этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163328/javascript-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-div) - получил следующее:

```
// вывожу в php ссылки, которые отдают данные ajax скрипту
<a style=\"{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}\" id=\"si_aa".$m4["id"]."\" onclick="getElem(this);">
    <div style=\"display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;\">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>
```

Ниже на этой же странице пишу следующее

```
<script>
function getElem(elem) {
   var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');
   var first_el = elems[0];

   if(first_el.getAttribute('active') == undefined || first_el.getAttribute('active') == '0') {
      first_el.style.backgroundColor = '#99DDFF';
      first_el.setAttribute('active', '1');
   }
   else {
      first_el.style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFFF';
      first_el.setAttribute('active', '0');
   }
}
</script>
```

Получается такой аналог чекбокса, и голубым отсвечиваются нажатые ссылки, которые при желании еще и можно отжать.

Можно ли так сделать, что при определенном количестве нажатых ссылок, больше ссылок нажимать будет нельзя, и все не нажатые ссылки заменят id на 0? (Хотя можно и не заменять id.)

Скажем, нажал человек сколько-то этих ссылок, как только отмечено 3, все остальные ссылки нельзя нажать (в идеале и id у них 0 станет) , пока не отжать одну обратно. Подскажете, можно ли так?

Comment: такой вопрос: id-шники ссылок известны?

Comment: Добавьте переменную-счетчик. Увеличивайте значение при каждом выделении ссылки и уменьшайте при "отжатии" ссылки. Так же перед нажатием ссылки проверяйте значение переменной. Если меньше 3 - смело жмите ссылку иначе просто пропускайте действия. 

Ну и по достижению счетчика нужного значения (в примере 3) просто пройдитесь по всем ссылкам и выставите нужный id

Comment: оу, привествую @lampa. id - неизвестны. по идее можно и без них. это в идеале с ними.

Comment: @mixalef - самый правильный вариант предложил @iKuzko

Comment: ох, не знаток JS. счетчик то не проблема, скажем в таком виде:

    id=\"si_aa".$m4["id"]."_aa_".count."\" 

вот остальное знать бы как. сами id менять не принципиально, интересует больше выделение фоном.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, может слегка и наговнокодил, но вот:

```
<script>
var count = 0;
var className = 'element';

function getElem(elem) {

    var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var first_el = elems[0];

   if(first_el.getAttribute('active') == undefined || first_el.getAttribute('active') == '0') {
        if(count >= 3) {
            return false;
        }

        first_el.style.backgroundColor = '#99DDFF';
        first_el.setAttribute('active', '1');
        //
        count++;
   }
   else {
        first_el.style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFFF';
        first_el.setAttribute('active', '0');
        //
        count--;
   }

   if(count >= 3) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if((new RegExp(className).test(elements[i].className))) {
                elems = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
                first_el = elems[0];

                if(first_el.getAttribute('active') == undefined || first_el.getAttribute('active') == '0') {    
                    first_el.className += 'disabled';
                }
            }
        }
   }

   return false;
}
</script>

<a style="{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}" id="si_aa" onclick="getElem(this);" class='element'>
    <div style="display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>

<a style="{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}" id="si_aa" onclick="getElem(this);" class='element'>
    <div style="display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>

<a style="{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}" id="si_aa" onclick="getElem(this);" class='element'>
    <div style="display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>

<a style="{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}" id="si_aa" onclick="getElem(this);" class='element'>
    <div style="display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>

<a style="{cursor:pointer;display:inline;}" id="si_aa" onclick="getElem(this);" class='element'>
    <div style="display:inline; padding:1px; border-radius:3px;">
        Слово
    </div>    
</a>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, спрашивал больше самому научиться. Теперь буду разбирать все до основания. Пожертвую немного очков опыта, т.к. реально просил сложное.

Comment: @mixalef только тут класс disabled не удаляется. Додумайте, как его удалить. Будет неплохим опытом.

Comment: ок, надо будет додумать

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте переменную-счетчик. Увеличивайте значение при каждом выделении ссылки и уменьшайте при "отжатии" ссылки. Так же перед нажатием ссылки проверяйте значение переменной.

Если меньше 3 - смело жмите ссылку иначе просто пропускайте действия.
Ну и по достижению счетчика нужного значения (в примере 3) просто пройдитесь по всем ссылкам и выставите нужный id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function getElem(elem) {
           var first_el = elem.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

           if(first_el.getAttribute('active') == undefined || first_el.getAttribute('active') == '0') {
              if (count > 2) return false;
              first_el.style.backgroundColor = '#99DDFF';
              first_el.setAttribute('active', '1');
              count++;
           } else {
              first_el.style.backgroundColor = 'FFFFFF';
              first_el.setAttribute('active', '0');
              count--;
           }
        }
        </script>
```